# Eigen: Should i use aligned map for intensive computations?

Tags: c++, eigen, matrix-multiplication, memory-alignment, eigen3

I want to perform a lot of computations over externally allocated data, especially matrix multiplications. It can be done via `Eigen::Map`. Unfortunately I'm not an expert in vectorized computations, but as far as i can see it's possible to specify `Aligned` flag for `Map`.

I decided to check performance difference between matrix multiplications via `Eigen::MatrixXf` and 'Eigen::Map':

```
void testMatProduct(
        const Eigen::MatrixXf &a,
        const Eigen::MatrixXf &b,
        Eigen::MatrixXf &res)
{
    const auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    res.noalias() = a * b;
    const auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( endTime - startTime ).count();
    std::cout << "Mat product elapsed " << duration / 1.0e6 << std::endl;
}

using EigenMap = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXf, Eigen::Unaligned>;

void testMapProduct(
        const EigenMap &a,
        const EigenMap &b,
        EigenMap &res)
{
    const auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    res.noalias() = a * b;
    const auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( endTime - startTime ).count();
    std::cout << "Map product elapsed " << duration / 1.0e6 << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char **)
{    
    srand(42);
    const int64_t N = 7000;
    const int64_t K = 6000;
    const int64_t M = 100;
    Eigen::MatrixXf mat1 = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(N, K);
    Eigen::MatrixXf mat2 = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(K, M);
    Eigen::MatrixXf matRes = Eigen::MatrixXf::Zero(N, M);

    // Copy data from mats to vecs
    Eigen::VectorXf vec1 = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXf>(mat1.data(), mat1.rows() * mat1.cols(), 1);
    Eigen::VectorXf vec2 = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXf>(mat2.data(), mat2.rows() * mat2.cols(), 1);
    Eigen::VectorXf vecRes = Eigen::VectorXf::Zero(N * M);

    EigenMap map1 = EigenMap(vec1.data(), mat1.rows(), mat1.cols());
    EigenMap map2 = EigenMap(vec2.data(), mat2.rows(), mat2.cols());
    EigenMap mapRes = EigenMap(vecRes.data(), matRes.rows(), matRes.cols());
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        testMapProduct(map1, map2, mapRes);
        testMatProduct(mat1, mat2, matRes);
        matRes.setZero();
        vecRes.setZero();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is not a valid benchmark but it should give me some intuition. I compile it with `-march=native` and it prints following output:

```
Map product elapsed 0.102751
Mat product elapsed 0.10224
Map product elapsed 0.10022
Mat product elapsed 0.100726
Map product elapsed 0.09963
Mat product elapsed 0.100697
Map product elapsed 0.099673
Mat product elapsed 0.100809
Map product elapsed 0.100195
.......
```

So it's seems to me that there are no big difference between map product and matrix product.

My questions are:
1) What the difference between `Map<MatrixXf, Unaligned>` and `Map<MatrixXf, Aligned>` in terms of performance? Should i care about `Map` alignment for other operations like dot products, elementwise addition, etc

2) Is my comparison correct?

PS Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Data alignment specifies the way how data is ought to be accessed and arranged. This means if you are using `Eigen::MatrixXf`, which refers to a matrix of unknown dimensions at compile-time with data type `float`, the data pointer should be aligned on a **4-byte (32-bits)** boundary (assuming float is represented using 32-bits on your system).

What impact on performance do different specifications of data alignment have? To answer this question, we will be taking a look at the following discussion:
[Talk: On a 32-bit architecture, would a 16-bit value not aligned on a 32-bit boundary be accessed more slowly?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Data_structure_alignment#On_a_32-bit_architecture,_would_a_16-bit_value_not_aligned_on_a_32-bit_boundary_be_accessed_more_slowly?)

- *Main argument that it affects performance:* Packing two 16-bit values into a 32-bit register means that you must spend resources on converting the data from one format to the other

One may argue that languages such as C/C++ support **sub-word accessing** which means you don't have to convert them, implying that you can save memory space and have no negative impact on performance.

I would assume that the Eigen library automatically detects that the data pointer for `Eigen::MatrixXf` is aligned on a 4 bytes boundary and therefore there are no performance implications if you leave out the `MapOption` template or assign it to `Eigen::Unaligned`. If you want to be sure use `Eigen::Aligned4` (recall that `Eigen::Aligned` is **deprecated** and a synonym for `Aligned16`, so 128-bits). You can take a look at the alignment enumerator [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__enums.html#ga45fe06e29902b7a2773de05ba27b47a1).

**2)** `Eigen::Map` enjoys the benefit that matrices and vectors can be initialized without copying data, unlike with `Eigen::Matrix` and `Eigen::Vector`. I'm pretty sure that `Eigen::Map` and `Eigen::Matrix` use the same operations for multiplying, addition, etc. objects underneath, just the referencing is different. The only performance benefit I can see from using `Eigen::Matrix` is **spatial locality** in terms of cache performance if `Eigen::Map` references to two matrices/vectors which are far apart in memory and when working with huge matrix sizes. Of course assuming that you initialized the two `Eigen::Matrix` objects just after another, such that they are contiguous in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is if the vectorized loads are aligned loads or unaligned loads (or when crossing cache line borders). On modern desktop CPUs (e.g. any CPU with AVX, IIRC), the difference will be minor and dwarfed by the actual work. On other devices, the penalty for non-aligned loads can vary significantly.

If the `Eigen::Map` is guaranteed that the memory is aligned, the loads can all be aligned loads, whereas if it's not guaranteed, then the loads must all be unaligned loads. How much this will affect your application will depend on what hardware you're targeting.